# Python call Java causes Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, python, django, subprocess

I am having issues to use the java program https://github.com/antonydeepak/ResumeParser/ in Django project in a localserver in MAC OS.

I have installed ResumeParser in the Django Project like:

-- Django Project
    -- app1
    -- app2
    -- ResumerParser

Here is my code but it says "Could not find or load main class".

```
if form.is_valid():
    f = form.save(commit=False)

    resume = form.cleaned_data['resume']

    cmd = ['java', '-cp', 'bin/:../GATEFiles/lib/:../GATEFiles/bin/gate.jar:lib/*', 'code4goal.antony.resumeparser.ResumeParserProgram %s textOutput.json' % resume]

    subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

Any clues of how to solve this? I've tried every post related to this theme in StackOverflow no success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two weeks I got it working.
All files must be copied to the ResumeParser/ResumeTransducer dir.

Also, there's a need to inform the current dir for file parsing.

Here is the implementation:

```
# first save the file
if form.is_valid():
    f = form.save(commit=False)

    resume = form.cleaned_data['resume']
    f.resume = resume
    f.save()

    # copy file to the CV parser dir so java can parse the file
    cf = "." + f.resume.url
    shutil.copy2(cf, 'ResumeParser/ResumeTransducer')

    # get file to convert
    fl_name = str(f.resume).split('/')[-1]

    # get file name to make json output
    base_name = os.path.splitext(fl_name)[0]

    cmd = "java -cp 'bin/*:../GATEFiles/lib/*:../GATEFiles/bin/gate.jar:lib/*' code4goal.antony.resumeparser.ResumeParserProgram %s %s.json" % (fl_name, base_name)

    # get the current working dir       
    os.chdir("ResumeParser/ResumeTransducer")

    # call java
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Thanks Jean-François Fabre!

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up well-delimiter parameters with parameters grouped with spaces.

```
cmd = ['java', '-cp', 'bin/:../GATEFiles/lib/:../GATEFiles/bin/gate.jar:lib/*', 'code4goal.antony.resumeparser.ResumeParserProgram %s textOutput.json' % resume]
```

Your last parameter is seen as a single parameter and is protected by spaces by `subprocess`:

`"code4goal.antony.resumeparser.ResumeParserProgram resume_value textOutput.json"`

=> The whole `"class<space>param1<space>param2"` is seen as your class: no wonder why it's not found.

Split *all* your parameters and it will work, `subprocess` won't group your parameters, no quoting (note the forced conversion of the `resume` object to `str`):

```
cmd = ['java', '-cp', 'bin/:../GATEFiles/lib/:../GATEFiles/bin/gate.jar:lib/*', 'code4goal.antony.resumeparser.ResumeParserProgram', str(resume),'textOutput.json']
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Now I have a new error: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

Comment: sorry! the `resume` object needed to be converted to a string, see my edit.